# Flink `/bin/sql-client.sh` throws NoSuchMethodError when reading from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

When trying to read from an Avro encoded Kafka topic, Flink throws a NoSuchMethodError:

```
./bin/sql-client.sh embedded -e environment.yml -l /opt/flink-1.10.0/library
[...]
Flink SQL> select * from VideoLabeled limit 10;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.metrics.KafkaMetricWrapper.<init>(Lorg/apache/kafka/common/Metric;)V
```

These are the jar's I've added in `/opt/flink-1.10.0/library`:

```
avro-1.9.1.jar
flink-avro-1.10.0.jar
flink-avro-1.10.0-sql-jar.jar
flink-cep_2.12-1.10.0.jar
flink-connector-kafka_2.12-1.10.0.jar
flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.12-1.10.0.jar
flink-table-common-1.10.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.10.3.jar
jackson-core-2.10.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar
kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar
```

I've probably messed up with the versions of these libraries, but can't figure out which I have to use. The docs say they should be 'ready-to-use JAR bundles', but I had to add for example the jackson libs to fix `NoClassDefFoundError`s.

What is the correct set of jars that will fix the `NoSuchMethodError` when reading Avro encoded Kafka messages with `sql-client.sh`?

### Edit 2020-04-03:

Removing `flink-avro-1.10.0.jar` and `flink-connector-kafka_2.12-1.10.0.jar` solve this error, but gives a deserialization error:

```
Flink SQL> select * from VideoLabeled limit 10;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -1
```

Comment: The problem is likely kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar, which clashes with the flink-connector-kafka_2.12-1.10.0.jar. You should be able to remove both of them, since the sql-connector-kafka jar should provide everything you need for interacting with Kafka. Similarly, flink-avro-1.10.0.jar shouldn't be required since the sql-jar version is present.

Comment: Can you give more details on the jackson issue?

Comment: Removing `flink-avro-1.10.0.jar` and `flink-connector-kafka_2.12-1.10.0.jar` indeed solved the NoSuchMethodError. Thanks! (see the original post for a follow-up question)

Also removing `kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar` results in `javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule` though. Removing the jackson libs gives a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: @RuurtjanPul Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Invisible: I gave up